# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'HOST'

Tags: python, flask, runtime-error

I have settings file defined as follows (config/settings.py):

```
HOST='localhost'
PORT='9001'
```

When I import settings in view and print the value of each one as follows, it prints correctly (views/user.py):

```
from ..config import settings

print settings.HOST
print settings.PORT
```

But when I use or print the same values from inside def it gives error (views/user.py):

```
from ..config import settings

print settings.HOST
print settings.PORT

@handle_error
def usersettings():
   print settings.HOST
   print settings.PORT
```

The function def when called in the above file gives error as follows:

```
ERROR:root:'function' object has no attribute 'HOST'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rahul/mywebapp/webapp/views/utils.py", line 36, in decorated_view
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/mywebapp/webapp/views/utils.py", line 27, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahul/mywebapp/webapp/views/user.py", line 344, in usersettings
    print settings.HOST
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'HOST'
```

> utils.py has decorated view named handle_error

My Package structure is as follows:

```
mywebapp/
   run.py
   webapp/
      __init__.py
      views/
         __init__.py
         utils.py
         user.py
      config/
         __init__.py
         settings.py
```

FYI: This use to work till last night and suddenly it has started behaving weird with the above error. Whats is a wrong that I am doing here?

EDIT:

My **init**.py are as follows:

```
from .utils import *
from .user import *
```

Comment: You need to show us more code. Some *other* code adds a `settings` *function* to that module. The function is not yet there when the module is imported (at least not where you print `settings.HOST`), but by the time `usersettings()` is *called*, `settings` has been rebound to a function object.

Comment: There is probably another `settings` function in your code, which explains this behaviour.

Comment: Can you show `user.py`?

Comment: Please grep through the whole codebase for any use of the string `settings` and check that there are no `def settings(...)` lines or `settings = something else`.

Comment: I have added my __init__.py for reference

Comment: Thanks guys... you all are correct.... by some how my user_settings function's initial name 'user_' was deleted causing this problem...I should have looked inside my user.py before posting query...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your `import` statement, there's probably a function named `settings` declared, or imported before `usersettings`. Python now recognizes the name `settings` as that function, not the module you imported.

To make sure this doesn't happen, you can put the part you needed straight after you import it:

```
from ..config import settings

HOST = settings.HOST
PORT = settings.PORT

...
```

And you can access it later when you like:

```
def usersettings():
    print HOST, PORT
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks... you all are correct.... by some how my user_settings function's initial name 'user_' was deleted causing this problem...I should have looked inside my user.py before posting query...